# is there a straightforward way to retrieve text that is rendered by the browser but is not hard-coded in the actual html file?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve data from a webpage but I cannot do it by making a web request and parsing the resulting html file because the actual text that I'm trying to retrieve is not in the html file! I imagine that this text is pulled using some script and for that reason it's not in the html file. For all I know I'm looking at the wrong data, but assuming that my theory is correct, is there a straightforward way to retrieve whatever text is displayed by the browser (Firefox or IE) rather than attempt to fetch the text from the html file?

Comment: Yes, you can (with certain limitations of course). What have you tried?

Comment: WebClient.DownloadString and HttpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

Comment: You will have to use a full-blown browser to do that job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to text that has been generated using Javascript in the browser.

You can use PhantomJS to achieve this: http://phantomjs.org/

It is essentially a headless browser that will process Javascript.

You may need to run this as ane xternal program but Im sure you can do that through C#

Answer (score 0):

Your other option would be to open the web page in a WebBrowser object which should execute the scripts, and then you can get the HtmlDocument object and go from there.

Take a look at this example...

```
    private void test()
    {
        WebBrowser wBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        wBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        wBrowser1.Url = new Uri("Web Page URL");
    }

    void wBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = (sender as WebBrowser).Document;
        // get elements and values accordingly. 
    }
```